# Java Trying to Connect to MQ w/ Exits

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I've written a standalone java program that needs to connect to an IBM MQ.

```
URL channelTabUrl = new URL("file:///C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\WebSphere MQ\\Data\\AMQCLCHL.TAB");
MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager("QueueManagerName", channelTabUrl);

MQQueueConnection connection = (MQQueueConnection) cf.createQueueConnection();
MQQueueSession session = (MQQueueSession) connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
MQQueue queue = (MQQueue) session.createQueue("queue:///queueName");
```

The error it is throwing me is a reason 2406: MQRC_CLIENT_EXIT_LOAD_ERROR. The IBM documentation is kind of vague, and I've already added by Exit64 directory to the classpath. What could I be missing here? Please let me know if I need to include additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MQRC_CLIENT_EXIT_LOAD_ERROR error means there was a failure to load the exit on the client side. There should be a nested/linked exception thrown that will provide more information i.e. ClassNotFoundException, as to why this happened. I suggest catching the exception in your code and then calling getCause() on the exception to see if it provides more details.

If you have added the Exit64 directory to the classpath then you would have to make sure you are using a 64bit JVM to run your java application rather than a 32bit JVM (java -version should provide you the details).